# Django: Save same formset multiple times

Tags: django, loops, formset

This might sound stupid, but I have a model_formset for a single model in my views that is passed to my template.  In my template I place the formset inside a loop:

```
<form action="generate/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for count in formset_count %}
        <p id="{{ count }}">{{ formset }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="submitbutton" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

formset_count is just a range of 1 to 5.  I have javascript that automatically enters the necessary values in the formset and each formset is slightly different.  I would like to submit and save all 5 formsets simultaneously by hitting the submit button once.

In my generate views I have the normal:

```
f = MyFormSet(request.POST)
if f.is_valid():
    f.save()
    return HttpResponse("Saved")
else:
    return HttpResponse(f.errors)
```

This saves only the last formset in the loop.

Is it possible to save all 5 formsets (the same formset with different values) at once using the modelformset_factory?

Answer (score 0):

I think your template needs a little work.  It looks like you're rendering the entire formset 5 times, with `<p id="{{ count }}">{{ formset }}</p>`.  You can also use [Django's built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for) `forloop.counter` to get the sequential numbering.

```
<form action="generate/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        <p id="{{forloop.counter}}">{{ form }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="submitbutton" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Your view code should be fine, [as per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view).

Comment: I am indeed trying to render the entire formset 5 times :).  My javascript makes sure that each form in each of the 5 formsets is completed correctly by utilizing the id="{{ count }}" element.  So each one of the multiple forms in the multiple formsets should be saved on submit.

Comment: In that case, I don't think Django can distinguish between the 5 formsets, and hence only the last one will be saved.  Why not instead pass 5 different formsets to your template?